# Nginx модуль nchat

Tags: nginx, curl

Локейшены nginx взяты из примера описания модуля NCHAT.

```
location = /sub {
    nchan_subscriber;
    nchan_channel_id foobar;
}

location = /pub {
    nchan_publisher;
    nchan_channel_id foobar;
}
```

Для добавления сообщения выполняем в командной строке:

```
curl --request POST --data "test message" -H "Accept: text/json" http://localhost/pub
```

Для получения информации о нем:

```
curl -v --request GET -H "Accept: text/json" http://localhost/pub
```

Последняя команда выведет:

> Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
>
> Trying 127.0.0.1...
>
> Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
>
> GET /pub HTTP/1.1
>
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
>
> Host: localhost
>
> Accept: text/json
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Server nginx/1.8.1 is not blacklisted
>
> Server: nginx/1.8.1
>
> Date: Mon, 29 Feb 2016 07:11:41 GMT
>
> Content-Type: text/json
>
> Content-Length: 78
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
>
> {"messages": 6, "requested": 799, GETbscribers": 0, "last_message_id": "0:0" }

Т.е. все работает. Из этого у меня появился такой вопрос: как вывести само сообщение а не информацию о нем?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно убрать ключ `-v` из запуска команды curl

Comment: У меня ничего не изменилось